# How to retrieve unique random key as soon as it had been updated?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with firebase. But I'm new to firebase. My app has an activity to upload post and here is the JSON structure.

```
post:{
  uid1:{
        -random1:{
                  text:hello,
                  uploader:John
                 },
         -random2:{
                  text:hello2334,
                  uploader:John
                 },
      },
  uid2:{
        -random3:{
                  text:Mornig,
                  uploader:Jack
                  },
      }

  }
likes:{
  uid1:{
        -random1:{
                  uid4:true,
                  uid5:true
                 },
        -random2:{
                  uid4:true,
                  uid3:true,
                 }
```

...
} 
Here is my example code when the user click on the submit button in order to upload his post..

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
                        post.push().setValue(textfield.getText());
                        /*I want to upload like node with the same random key but with different value. I don't know how to do it*/
                             }
                 });
```

When the user click post,I update post with random key and then I want to update the like with the same random key.I don't know how to upload to node with same random key at the same time(only uid and random id node)as I'm a noob. I've search a lot but no answer was found.
Sorry for my bad English writing skill...

Comment: Instead of describing your code, please share the [minimal actual code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This makes it much more likely that some can help, although cutiko was kind enough to already make an educated guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the key before you write the data. You are usibg push method so that will create the key, for getting it before you need to use push but also use setValue

```
ref = root.child("post").child(uid);
key = ref.push().key //it could be getKey() depending on the sdk
ref.child(key).setValue(yourObject);
root.child("likes").child(ownerUid).child(key).child(uid).setValue(true)
```

Comment: Do you mean I can get the random key before updating?I'll test it tomorrow because it is too late to sleep.Thank you...

Comment: I mean, is there a stand by unique random key to upload a child? I was always thinking that random key is created at the server after updating.

Comment: You can get the auto generated key before writting the database and it is only pseudo random it use the client time as part of the algorithm, you can see the full explanation here http://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html

Comment: Thank you ...Its work fine....:) By the way, let me know the best database for post and likes. I don't think my database structure is good. So can you give me some advice ?